# How to put one view over another relativelayout in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I searched a lot but nothing seems to work in my case. Here is what I want to achieve using relative layout. [image]

below is my xml code for it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/microphone" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_16">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow"
        android:text="@string/previous"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

By doing this the microphone is hidden behind the Next-Previous Strip. I guess there is some parameter to control the view height in z-axis but I don't remember that and will it work below Lolipop too. Please help.

Comment: Okay , I found that `android:elevation="10dp"` bring the view in front by increasing z-axis. But will it work below Lolipop ?

Comment: `nothing seems to work` ... Probably a [**FloatingActionButton**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) will.

Comment: Just move the button definition to the end of your layout.

Comment: Mind that **nested layouts are bad for performances**. Try to **keep your hyerarchy as flat as possible**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show your "Microphone Layout", you don't have to do much with your current layout(xml)

Just put your "**Microphone Relative Layout**" after "**Previous and Next Relative Layout**", like below

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_16">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow"
            android:text="@string/previous"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/microphone"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps you.